# Primefaces: Update (refresh) p:panel inside p:rowExpansion

Tags: ajax, primefaces, datatable

I have the following configuration:
JSF: Apache MyFaces JSF-2.1 Core API (Version: 2.1.10)
PrimeFaces 3.4.2
Tomcat 7.0.35

I have a DataTable with rowExpansion and a panel with button in the rowExpansion. I would like to refresh only the panel inside the rowExpansion when the user clicks on the button.

```
<p:dataTable id="vmt" var="vmtemplate" value="#{myViewBean.myList}" rowKey="#{vmtemplate.id}">
        <p:ajax event="rowToggle" listener="#{myViewBean.onRowToggle}" update=":growl" /> 
     <p:column style="width:2%"><p:rowToggler /></p:column>
     <p:column>...</p:column>
        <p:rowExpansion>
         <p:panel id="exp_panel" header="#{vmtemplate.name} Instances">
      <h:form id="instancesForm">
                                <p:commandButton id="refreshRowExpPanel" title="Refresh" update=":growl" action="#{myViewBean.reloadData}"/> 
          </h:form>                                 
          </p:panel>
     </p:rowExpansion>
</p:dataTable>
```

I think I have to set the update property of the refreshRowExpPanel button in order to refresh the exp_panel, but when I set it to update=":growl :expanel" I get an error:

> Cannot find component with identifier ":expanel" referenced from
>   "mainForm:vmt:0:refreshRowExpPanel".

so the generated ID of the panel is "mainForm:vmt:0:refreshRowExpPanel", but when I specify this to the update (update=":mainForm:vmt:0:refreshRowExpPanel") I got the same error:

> Cannot find component with identifier
>   ":mainForm:vmt:0:refreshRowExpPanel" referenced from
>   "mainForm:vmt:0:refreshRowExpPanel".

with update=":mainForm" it works, but it refreshes the whole dataTable and my expanded row will be closed, so it's not fine.

Could you please suggest a solution how to refresh only my panel inside the rowExp, maybe from JS, or any other idea?

thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just realized, that I had a form outside my dataTable:

```
<h:form id="outerForm">
<p:dataTable id="vmt" var="vmtemplate" value="#{myViewBean.myList}" rowKey="#{vmtemplate.id}">
pansion>
...
</p:dataTable>
</form>
```

by removing the outer form, and changing the update value to "@form" solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to try using ID of the panel without colon on the beginning, so:

```
update="mainForm:vmt:0:refreshRowExpPanel"
```

Also you may like to read this post about [making references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier/8644762#8644762).